# Advantages & Disadvantages of Dependency-Injecting Non-Instantiable Objects

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, dependency-injection, refactoring

What, in your opinion, are the advantages and disadvantages of dependency-injecting non-instantiable objects in **JavaScript**?

Some context you may want to explore are:

- **Unit-testing**

  - Is it worth dep-injecting it? After all, you can overwrite the non-instantiable "static" dependency to a fake object for each test even without dep-injection.
- **Refactoring**

  - Will it become more difficult to locate & refactor the non-instantiable dependency?
- **Readability**

  - Which implementation is easier to follow? Is the implicitness or explicitness important to you?
- **File-size**

### Code

Non-instantiable object:

```
WindowFactory = {
  buildWindow: function() {
     return {};
  }
};
```

Dependency-Injected:

```
(House = function(windowFactory) {
  this.windowFactory = windowFactory;
}).prototype = {
  build: function() {
    var window = this.windowFactory.buildWindow();
  }
};

var house = new House(WindowFactory);
```

vs. The Non-Dependency-Injected variant:

```
(House = function() {
}).prototype = {
  build: function() {
    var window = WindowFactory.buildWindow();
  }
};

var house = new House();
```

### Context

My primary goal is to make the code above testable. I've gotten into a 
habit of externalizing instantiable dependencies (e.g `var window = new 
Window(); var house = new House(window);`). This helps when unit- 
testing instantiable objects (e.g. `House`), since instead of the real 
dependencies (`Window`) I can instantiate the object with a fake (`var 
fakeWindow = {}; var house = new House(fakeWindow);`), and not have to 
worry about redundantly testing the dependencies while testing my 
object. (This form of dependency-injection is also useful when testing 
objects that depend on some data being retrieved via XHR, DOM-events, 
sessionStorage, or cookie.)

Now, when the dependency is an instantiable object itself, the 
benefits are clear to me; but when the dependency is a non- 
instantiable object (e.g. WindowFactory in the code above), I have 
second thoughts about the usefulness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get some gain in unit-testing, that might be more than enough for me. You'll be able to cleanly test the functionality without depending on global/external state. The added bonus then becomes the readability; you clearly show which global state/api you depend on in the arguments of your function.

Being able to change the static methods in the setup/teardown of the tests is a workaround for the problem, but I personally find it to be error-prone and a chore doing it.